# Export report from selenium

Tags: selenium, crystal-reports

I want to export a Crystal Report from my application using selenium. I click on the export button using selenium webdriver, but after that nothing happens. How can I resolve this?

EDIT: I was able to click on the export button but now there is a native dailog box that comes up with three buttons. I have to click on save. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some javascript related problem. Please use this

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

If your problem will not sort-out then please share the attachment